# Neural network vs SARIMA

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, arima, seasonality, spectral-analysis

In real-time data, sometimes you find that you cannot get a certain seasonality for the data because it is difficult to identify.  This happens a lot in the prices of commodities and the stock market and stock prices and in many other technical or environmental data such as rain, etc.  Using the Arima seasonal model is therefore difficult.  The Question: Is it possible to use spectral analysis especially periodigram versus the period to determine the seasonality and is it possible to use the cyclicity determined by the chart as seasonality?  For such data is the use of a neural network will be helpful rather than using SARIMA?.  I know that all expectations are false but I am looking for the best way for forecasting

Answer (score 2):

There exist ways you can test seasonality. Though plots are useful you should test your assumed seasonality with cross validation.

The topic of neural networks and forecasting is not as well developed as it is for other fields. DeepAR has shown some success, but with these methods come additional computational costs. You can also search for pretrained neural networks for forecasting for something cheaper.